# django list of images

Tags: django, database, performance

i'd like to create a model of a good for an online shop. the model should contain a number of images. i have two approaches to do that:

1)

```
class Good(models.Model):
    ...

class Img(models.Model):
    img = models.ImageField(...
    good = models.ForeignKey("Good", ...
```

2)

```
class Good(models.Model):
    img = models.ForeignKey('ChainImg', ...

class ChainImg(models.Model):
    img = models.ImageField(...
    anotherimg = models.ForeignKey("ChainImg", ...
```

as i understand to get all images for a good:

in case of 1) rows in the "Img" table will be filtered for id of the good, and if i have 100 goods, the table will be filtered 100 times for 100 different ids.

in case of 2) if an average good has 10 pictures chained, the "Img" table will be queried 10 times to return 10 rows by their ids. So for 100 goods "Img" table will be queried about 1000 times by ids, but no filtering is needed. ChainImg could also point to itself and create a problem. but that can be avoided.

Which approach would be better? Faster? More efficient? Correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First approach is the correct one in this situation.

In first case you can have a simple loop `for image in good.images: do something` statement.

In second case you will have to perform multiple lookups on the same table, which will require a loop to perform multiple JOINs on the same table, which is unnecessary complication.